How to calculate difference between 2 columns in power bi table visualization
I have a table visualization created in power BI dashboard and it has 3 columns. I want to find the difference between col1 and col2 and display as diff.  I have written a measure but it is giving me random numbers as output. Aug-All-Countries-Raw is the name of the table that is loaded from excel into PBI desktop. Please help to solve this.
What I have is below



country
Col 1
Col 2




America
134
129


Singapore
10
10



What I'm getting after applying measure is below:
Diff = sum('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col1]) - sum('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col2])



country
Col 1
Col 2
Diff




America
134
129
119


Singapore
10
10
10



What I want is below



Country
Col 1
Col 2
Diff




America
134
129
5


Singapore
10
10
0



Tried to create a measure but it is showing wrong output. measure used is -  Diff = sum('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col1]) - sum('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col2])

I found a way after trying much. I used below Quick measure and it's working fine now.
Diff  =
SUM('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col1]) - DISTINCTCOUNT('Aug-All-Countries-Raw'[Col2])
However I did not understand how the SUM helps to find difference. Will be helpful if someone explains.
